Firebase: Offline - no result unless I force close App and reopen
Why is it, that my data is not showing when I log into my App (IOS)? If I force close and reopen it knows that I am logged in, and then shows data.
My config.js:
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.firestore().settings({ cacheSizeBytes: firebase.firestore.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED, merge: true, ignoreUndefinedProperties: true });
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence().catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

Then when the app is called and it detects they are logged in:
{window.location.href="/dashboard"}

Dashboard is where I call all the data from firebase.
I have the package dependencies in my app, and import them (appDelegate):
import UIKit
import Capacitor
import FacebookCore
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth

FirebaseApp.configure()

Am I missing something? No error appears in Xcode console...

There is nothing in that code that actually reads data from Firebase. The login sequence is also not clear; for example, you could be forgetting to call any code that loads data from Firebase upon user authentication, whereas it's 'automatically' called upon App start because the user info is already cached. The question needs clarity.
